# Uploading BLOB from ts through django API to DB

Tags: django, typescript, database, post

I'm trying to upload some logData but in my database the informationfield is always empty, everything else gets uploaded correctly.

I've tried two differnt ways, neither of them seem to work. I uploaded everything packed in a formdata with the logData as blob/string/... nothing worked
The other way was creating an Object based on an interface and adding all the information (here aswell i tried string and blob) both didn't work, the field on the Database is always empty.

I'm curios if i did something wrong cause the data should be in the database saved as log.csv with the hexstring in it

i get the data as an UInt8Array

ATM it looks like this:

```
 const test = new Blob([locAdjustmentBlob])

 const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("log_user", locUser)
        formData.append("log_adjustment_blob", test)

 await store.state.apiHandler.postForm("/raw/logs/", formData)
```

And in the the API:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    log_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    log_user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    log_adjustment_blob = models.BinaryField()
```

If you need more information just ask
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make the binary field editable and upload a base64 string
Also it's not in a form anymore, i just post the log object i created